# Three.js Mirrored Normal Maps Flipped Channel

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have added a normal map to a model in Three.js that is mirrored down the middle. It looks like one of the channels (green perhaps?) is flipped on the mirrored side.

[image]

I have one ambient light, one directional headlight, and one spotlight. Here is the code that I use to make the material:

```
// Create a MeshPhongMaterial for the model
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(texture_color);
// Wrapping modes
//THREE.RepeatWrapping = 1000;
//THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping = 1001;
//THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping = 1002;
material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
material.map.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
if (texture_normal != null) {
    material.normalMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(texture_normal);
    material.normalMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    material.normalMap.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
}
material.wrapAround = true;
material.morphTargets = true;
material.shininess = 15;
material.specular = new THREE.Color(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
material.ambient = new THREE.Color(0, 0, 0);
material.alphaTest = 0.5;
var mesh = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh( geometry, material );
// Turn on shadows
mesh.castShadow = true;

if (shadows) {
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
}

scene.add( mesh );
```

I tried all of the different combinations of `material.normalMap.wrapS` and `material.normalMap.wrapT` but that didn't solve it (tried diffuse map too). What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an older version (1.2) of the Blender Three.js exporter. By switching to the latest version (1.5) of the exporter from the r67 repository, <strike>Three.js now correctly handles mirrored normal maps with its Phong shader out of the box.</strike>

Edit: The Phong Shader was still having issues with the flipped channel. I ended up using the "Normal Map Shader" (see the Three.js examples) and that gave me correct results. Unfortunately the Normal Map Shader doesn't work with Morph animations, only Skeletal.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example where the `Phong` shader was unsatisfactory for your needs, but the `NormalMap` shader was acceptable? The three.js site may be the most appropriate place to post.

Comment: Do you mean the three.js github site? If so, would you like me to open a new issue or add this to the one that I had recently closed (and reopen it)?

Comment: I would suggest a link to a _simple_ live example. You can post it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Normal maps are dependent on the geometry, so you can't just mirror it and expect it to work like a diffuse texture would.

To make it work, you need to flip the normal map's red channel wherever the UVWs are mirrored on the model.

http://www.polycount.com/forum/showthread.php?t=116922

Comment: Red channel! I was close. That sounds like the issue alright. Any idea how I can do that in Three.js? This seems like a common issue that should have a dedicated function to address it.