# What's the best way to use mirrored Normal Maps in THREE.JS?

Tags: three.js, normals

[Three.js Mirrored Normal Maps Flipped Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208504/three-js-mirrored-normal-maps-flipped-channel)

[image: Normal map errors visible above back left thigh]

[image: Mirrored seam]

I'm using 3dsmax 2013 (FBX 2013) with tangents and binormals included. I'm also setting :

```
Horse_normalMap.wrapS = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
```

However it seems that even by flipping the mirrored UVs back to their non-flipped original state (and then flipping them in THREE.JS) it means the red channel is still inverted. I tried to debug the tangents using the TangentsHelper but that seems to have been removed from what I've read. I may have to go back to using unmirrored UVs unless there's a good workaround.

I looked briefly/hopefully into derivative maps as they seemed to offer a wayout from tangent based mismatches; but the few examples all seem to use the same displacement map and not the typical deriv 2-channel maps written about elsewhere. I tried 3 different displacement map generators (HP>LP) and all gave me very noisy results. There doesn't seem to be any docs on what it expects, I did come across an open bug report (sorry not enough rep to post more than 2 links) which suggests this is an open issue still.

Comment: Yes, go back to using unmirrored UVs. three.js does not utilize geometry tangents in its built-in shaders. You can file an enhancement request to honor `MirroredRepeatWrapping` in normal maps if you want, but there has been minimal demand for that feature -- especially since there is a workaround.

Comment: OK thanks for letting me know. It's a shame since the workaround requires double the texture memory (if both sides get their share of the 0-1 UV space) or (from what I understand) writing custom code to flip the normal map info for just half the mesh at runtime (therefore doubling the drawcalls by requiring separate materials assigns). I guess it'd also require baking into a render texture. After I've finished the art assets I may look into this but I expect it'd be too expensive for mobile. If you get a chance please check out my other question on Derivative Maps.